# Accessing variables in other ViewControllers Swift

Tags: ios, swift, variables, viewcontroller

I have a user login to through a welcome screen in my app. Now I want that username to pass on to the other view controllers I have in the rest of the app, however i cannot figure out how. In old C i would have done an #import viewcontroller but that is not working.

I have one LoginVC where I set the username from a regular field

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var txtUsername : UITextField!
```

now I want to show that txtUsername variable in my ActionVC as a regular var preferably in a function - however I have no idea how?

```
func accessOtherViewController(){
    var userName = LoginVC(txtUsername)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var myCustomViewController: SomeViewController = SomeViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    var getThatValue = myTableView.someVariable
```

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit? using the LoginVC and otherViewController names form the example above?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public var to access variables in other view controllers.

At the top of your viewcontroller class add `public var name = "saucepan";`

You should access this var in other view controllers if you only type the name of the var it will turn green (depending on your color scheme).

Comment: sorry no go. are you sure this is workable in swift?

Comment: it does not when i implement it so perhaps you can share some of you knowledge in code then?